# Find transitive closure of the relation, given its matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Find transitive closure of relation  $R$ described by the matrix $M_R$:

$$M_R = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &0 \\0 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I tried doing it like this $M_R \cdot M_R \cdot M_R$ but could not get the answer.

Comment: Do you mean the transitive closure of the graph (or relation) described by this matrix?

Comment: Transitive closure of R if Mr is a given matrix

Comment: So I guess you mean $M_R$, the matrix associated with the relation $R$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, i wanted to write that but i did not how

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The relation indicated by this matrix can be described as
$$
(x,x) \quad x = 1,2,3\\
(2,3)\\
(3,1)
$$
In order for the relation to be transitively closed, you need to add $(2,1)$.  So, the matrix we want is
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&0\\
1&1&1\\
1&0&1
}
$$